# Fast method to select matrix elements based on a vector of positions

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, filtering

There is an operation for which I have long wanted to find a better solution.

Let:

- `a` be a matrix of dimensions $m\times n$
- `v` be an integer vector of length $n$ with elements drawn from $[1, m]$

For every element $x$ at position $p$ in `v` I wish to select the element at row $x$, column $p$ in `a`.

Example:

```
SeedRandom[0]

a = Array[Range[7] 10^# &, 3, 0]

v = RandomInteger[{1,3}, 7]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
>  10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 \\
>  100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 & 600 & 700 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>
> ```
> {3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1}
> ```

Desired output:

```
{100, 200, 30, 4, 5, 600, 7}
```

---

#### Details:

- Although a compiled function is likely to be the fastest approach for packed arrays I want something more general, allowing arrays of mixed types, and ideally optimized for arrays in which each row is a packed array (list) of a different type, e.g.

  $\left(
  \begin{array}{ccccccc}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
   0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.6 & 0.7 \\
   \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{g} \\
  \end{array}
  \right)$
- I am still interested in seeing the fastest possible compiled function as it may serve as the basis for a general solution as well.
- I seek a solution that works well for any shape of array `a`, from $n\gg m$ to square to $m\gg n$, though if compromise is necessary I would optimize for $n > m$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems fast(er):

```
Extract[a, Transpose[{v, Range@Length@v}]]
```

---

**Addendum**

Mr.Wizard's clean method

```
Diagonal @ a[[v]]
```

has a surprising property for those of us who think that packed arrays rank just below the wheel in the list of inventions for the sake of efficiency.  For unpacked arrays `a`, it uses virtually no extra memory.

**Example**

*Initialization.*  Start with a fresh kernel.  After quitting is finished, initialize `a` and `v`.

```
Quit[]

SeedRandom[0]
a = RandomReal[1, {50, 10000}];
v = RandomInteger[{1, 50}, 10000];
```

*Example 1.* In the case `a` is a packed array, `a[[v]]` is computed and fills memory.

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]
Diagonal@a[[v]]; // AbsoluteTiming
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*
  32251456
  {0.420822, Null}
  831474792
*)
```

*Example 2.* Below `unpacked` is not packed. Evidently filling memory with `unpacked[[v]]` is deferred and `Diagonal` is computed without expanding `unpacked[[v]]` further.

```
unpacked = a; unpacked[[1, 1]] = "x";

MaxMemoryUsed[]
Diagonal@unpacked[[v]]; // AbsoluteTiming
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*
  55228232
  {0.001294, Null}
  55566776
*)
```

*Example 3.* (**Edit**) There is a way to take some advantage of this to improve the performance of `Diagonal` on packed array by partial unpacking and using `Tr`.  See [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) answer, under **Update**.

---

For comparison purposes with examples 1 and 2, here are my timings for the `Extract` method:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming@ Do[Extract[a, Transpose[{v, Range@Length@v}]], {100}] /100
(*
  0.00009192
*)

First@AbsoluteTiming@ Do[Extract[unpacked, Transpose[{v, Range@Length@v}]], {100}] /100
(*
  0.00057431
*)
```

Comment: This is just the sort of thing I was looking for.  Funny how easy it seems *now* but so do many great ideas.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

*Edit: please see **Update** below.*

Although I am self-answering, as stated, I am not satisfied with these approaches.
Nevertheless they may be useful and they can serve as a benchmark for any new solutions.

This is cleanest method I know, though sadly it is a true memory hog, and not fast either:

```
Diagonal @ a[[v]]
```

> ```
> {100, 200, 30, 4, 5, 600, 7}
> ```

More practically but still slow:

```
MapThread[Part, {a\[Transpose], v}]
```

Even slower:

```
MapIndexed[a[[#, First @ #2]] &, v]
```

Auto-compilation in `Table` makes it much faster for fully packed arrays but elsewhere it is slower than `MapThread`, including mixed arrays where every row is packed.

```
Table[a[[ v[[i]], i ]], {i, Length@v}]
```

---

#### Observation:

Notably only the first approach uses `v` directly without iterating over it, and it is impractical due to the huge expression created.  I wonder if I have overlooked a way to perform a vectorized extraction without that memory explosion.

---

### Update

[Michael](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) astutely observed:

> If `unpacked` is not a packed array, `Diagonal@unpacked[[v]]` is pretty fast and uses almost no extra memory.

Looking at this again I realize there are two problems:

1. When extracting rows from a fully packed array the expressions are not memory-shared
2. `Diagonal` fully unpacks

The first problem can be avoided by unpacking the outermost level of the array, and the second by using a function that does not unpack: [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tr.html).

Combined:

```
(List @@ a)[[v]] ~Tr~ List
```

> ```
> {100, 200, 30, 4, 5, 600, 7}
> ```

As an alternative to `List @@ a` we can use the seemingly inert replacement `h_[x__] :> h[x]` to unpack the outer level.  This leads to a rather fun definition:

```
h_[x__] ~f~ v_ := h[x][[v]] ~Tr~ h
```

This revised method actually performs quite well, though it is still half as fast as `Extract` on unpacked data and more than an order of magnitude behind on a packed array.

Comment: If `unpacked` is not a packed array, `Diagonal@unpacked[[v]]` is pretty fast and uses almost no extra memory.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great observation!  I'm so glad I posted this question.  Why don't you put that in your answer too, so it doesn't get lost?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please see **Update**

Comment: I thought about exploring unpacking just the first level, but I didn't have time.  I doubt I would have come up with `Tr`, and I'm sure I wouldn't have come up with such a cute definition. It would be worth another upvote, if I could. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with a sparse array:

```
s = SparseArray[
   MapThread[({#1, #2} -> 1) &,
    {
     Range[Length[v]],
     (v - 1)*Length[v] + Range[Length[v]]
     }], {Length[v], Times @@ Dimensions[a]}];

s.Flatten[a, 1]
```

But sadly, `Flatten` will take a long time for large `a`. (If you could keep around `Flatten[a]` for many "queries", it might be competitive, though).

Comment: That is unlike anything I tried.  I do like the idea of using `Dot`.  With some data you will find that `Join @@ a` is faster than `Flatten[a, 1]`. Thanks for a novel idea. +1

Comment: Your method inspired this idea: `Flatten[a, 1][[Subtract[v, 1] # + Range[#] & @ Length @ v]]`.  It's pretty good but still not as fast as `Extract`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be fast.

```
  a[[v[[#]], #]] & /@ Range[Length@v];
```

Comment: I haven't yet found a case where this is particularly good.  In a single test on fully packed data it is not as fast as `Table`, and on unpacked data it is slower than `Table` and significantly slower than `MapThread`.  Have you found a case where this is faster than the options in my own answer?

Comment: I checked it with this: SeedRandom[0] 
a = RandomReal[100, {13000, 13000}];
v = RandomInteger[{1, 13000}, 13000];. I got zero Timing.

Comment: For me `Table` still performs better with that data but this is not far off and it's another option. +1