# Does Mathematica have Month Range and Day range?

Tags: functions, date-and-time

It is known that `CharacterRange["a", "z"]` gives list of characters from a to z. Does *Mathematica* have something similar for weekdays and months of the year? Something like:

```
Somefunction["Saturday", "Friday"]
(* {"Saturday", "Sunday", ...} *)

Somefunction["January", "December"]    
(* {"January ", "February ", ...} *)
```

Comment: Maybe you should clarify "Week Days": http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=3385&idForum=4&lang=de&lp=ende. And why start with "Saturday"? As far as I know a new week starts in the United States with Sunday, whereas in most European countries it's Monday. Aside from this a +1 question :)

Comment: @eldo, Just random selection of days :)

Comment: Agree, Like the "French Republican Calendar".

Comment: If you didn't find it in the documentation it's probably not there. With all due respect I think this is just a way of asking for an implementation without having to respond to the question "what did you try?"

Comment: @Pickett I think you know that there are so many things undocumented. I am not trying anything other than finding some way to get things done easier. I am still learning MMA and I am not aware of so many things in this program :)

Comment: @Algohi In this case I would write down the solutions that I knew of, include them in the question and specify what I don't like about them. This way you are saving others time and the question will be more focused. See for example rasher's question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43785/drop-selection-of-columns-from-a-ragged-array). You can also answer your own question, like Mr.Wizard did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55921/fast-method-to-select-matrix-elements-based-on-a-vector-of-positions). Just my advice, don't take it too seriously.

Comment: @Pickett thanks. I will keep your advice in mind :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### For full ranges

There is the function `DayRange` that can be used for this purpose, but not in the same simple way like `CharacterRange`.
For the days:

```
DayName /@ DayRange[Today, Today ~DatePlus~ {{1, "Week"}, {-1, "Day"}}]
```

> ```
> {Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday}
> ```

For the months:

```
DateValue[#, "MonthName"] & /@ DayRange[Today, Today ~DatePlus~ {1, "Year"}] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> ```
> {"August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"}
> ```

If you need a special order, `Today` can be replaced with a suitable `DateObject`.

---

Or shorter and faster for the month range:
Day Range:

```
DayName[DateObject[{2014, 09, #}]] & /@ Range[7]
```

> ```
> {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday}
> ```

Month Range:

```
(DateValue[#, "MonthName"] &@DateObject[{2014, #, 01}]) & /@ Range[12]
```

> ```
> {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
> ```

---

### For arbitrary ranges

For arbitrary month ranges:

```
monthRange[month1_String, month2_String] :=
 Module[{m1 = DateList[month1][[;; 2]], m2 = DateList[month2][[;; 2]], i},
  Reap@For[i = 0,
   DateValue[m1 + i, "MonthName"] != DateValue[m2, "MonthName"],
   i++,
   Sow@DateValue[m1 + i, "MonthName"]
   ] // Last // Flatten // Append[month2]
 ]
```

For arbitrary day ranges:

```
dayRange[day1_String, day2_String] :=
 Module[{date1 = (DateList@DayPlus[Today, 1, Symbol[day1]])[[;; 3]], day2Symbol = Symbol[day2], i},
  Reap@For[i = 0,
   DayName@(date1 + {0, 0, i}) != day2Symbol,
   i++,
   Sow@ToString@DayName@(date1 + {0, 0, i})
   ] // Last // Flatten // Append[day2]
 ]
```

and the function overload for symbolic days

```
dayRange[day1_Symbol, day2_Symbol] :=
 Module[{date1 = (DateList@DayPlus[Today, 1, day1])[[;; 3]], i},
  Reap@For[i = 0,
   DayName@(date1 + {0, 0, i}) != day2,
   i++,
   Sow@DayName@(date1 + {0, 0, i})
   ] // Last // Flatten // Append[day2]
 ]
```

---

And for those who can't stand procedual programming

```
monthRange2[month1_String, month2_String] :=
 Module[{d1 = DateList[month1][[2]], d2 = DateList[month2][[2]], range},
  range = If[d2 < d1, Range[d1, 12 + d2], Range[d1, d2]];
  (DateValue[#, "MonthName"] & @ DateObject[{2014, #, 01}]) & /@ range
]
```

and

```
dayRange2[day1_String, day2_String] :=
 Module[{date1 = DayPlus[Today, 1, Symbol@day1], date2},
  date2 = DayPlus[date1 ~DayPlus~ -1, 1, Symbol@day2];
  ToString@*DayName /@ date1 ~DayRange~ date2
]
```

with the overload

```
dayRange2[day1_Symbol, day2_Symbol] :=
 Module[{date1 = DayPlus[Today, 1, day1], date2},
  date2 = DayPlus[date1 ~DayPlus~ -1, 1, day2];
  DayName /@ date1 ~DayRange~ date2
]
```

Answer (score 7):

**1)** Get the list of days and months. Note that days are represented in MMA as symbols (and not strings as months are), hence the use of `ToString` to make them in a consistent type with the list of months (credit to @Mr.Wizard for this tip).

```
monthList=DateValue[{2014,#,1},"MonthName"]&/@Range[12]
(* {January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December} *)

dayList=DateValue[{2014,1,#},"DayName"]&/@Range[7]//Map[ToString,#]&
(* {Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday} *)
```

**2)** Define a function that take a starting month and an ending month. Rotate month list until the first month of the list is the defined starting month. Then, trim the months after the ending month.

```
Clear[monthRange]
monthRange[start_?(MemberQ[monthList,#]&),end_?(MemberQ[monthList,#]&)]:=Module[{rotated},
rotated=NestWhile[RotateLeft,monthList,(First@#!=start&)];
rotated/.{a___,end,b___}:>{a,end}]

monthRange["March","January"]
(* {March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December,January} *)
```

**3)** Do the same for the day list.

```
Clear[dayRange]
dayRange[start_?(MemberQ[dayList,#]&),end_?(MemberQ[dayList,#]&)]:=Module[{rotated},
rotated=NestWhile[RotateLeft,dayList,(First@#!=start&)];
rotated/.{a___,end,b___}:>{a,end}]

dayRange["Wednesday","Monday"]
(* {Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday} *)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. :-)  If I had known you were writing this I might not have written mine.  FYI: You can use `RotateLeft` in place of `RotateLeft[#,1]&`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Appreciate the compliment especially coming from you.

Comment: Since you're open to them: I recommend using `Symbol` instead of `ToExpression` as it is more focused and "safer" – however I would eliminate that aspect altogether and simply use `ToString /@` on `dayList` as I think the input and output types should match.  (If we input String day names we should get a list of Strings.)

Comment: Doh! Also I now learn of a new use of `Symbol` aside from pattern heads.

Comment: Reading your answer I am embarrassed about my own so I deleted it.  I am inspired to write something better based on your methods.  May I (later) edit your answer to include it, or shall I post it as my own?

Comment: Please feel free to edit my answer (or post your own if that's what you prefer). I'd be more than honored.

Comment: If I come up with something good I'll include it in your answer, but it will probably be tomorrow.  Here's a teaser of one method, should you choose to use it yourself: `Join[#, #] & @ monthList /. {___, seq : PatternSequence["October", ___, "May"], ___} :> {seq}`

Comment: @seismatica - I just downvoted your answer, because you don't show any effort to compare it with Karsten's answer given 1 hour earlier.

Comment: @eldo I came up with the first step on my own and as far as I could recall my answer was posted before Karsten's edit to add the quick method at the end. Both methods generate the same list of dates and months, though mine also include functions to find the range between 2 arbitrary momths/days. Please let me know what I can improve on in my answer and I'd be more than happy to accommodate.

Comment: @seismatica - I believe you're right. But my `StockExchange` in Germany still shows that @Karsten posted his answer 3 hours ago, whereas all the subsequent answers and comments are 1 hour ago. Relativity of calendars. I'll make it good.

Comment: @eldo my "faster" edit and seismatica's answer where posted within seconds. No one stole that from anyone. Moreover our approaches are quite different. +1 (+ I thought the OP just wanted "a" to "z" or rather "January" to "December")

Comment: @Karsten 7. Thanks for your gentle answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's fun to use `Associations` as a circular linked list, which automatically handles the cyclic nature of these ranges:

```
Clear@monthRange
monthRange[start_, end_] := Module[{monthsLL, head},
    monthsLL = Fold[
        <|#2 -> #|> &,    
        Reverse[DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`MonthList["Gregorian"] ~Join~ {monthsLL}]
    ];
    head = NestWhile[First, monthsLL, Keys@# != {start} &];
    NestWhileList[First, head, Keys@# != {end} &] // Keys /* Flatten
]
```

You can use any other list (e.g. days of week) instead of `` DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`MonthList `` to create a similar "range" function.

```
monthRange["December", "April"]
(* {"December", "January", "February", "March", "April"} *)

monthRange["March", "August"]
(* {"March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"} *)
```

You can also define the linked list outside the function instead of creating it each time, if performance is critical. For most use cases, this will not be an issue.

Comment: +1, Very nice to see the undocumented things is there  any thing similar to ``DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`MonthList`` for week list? that would be the perfect answer for this question.

Comment: I would also be grateful if you tell me where to find these undocumented functions of mathematica. where and how do you get them? :)

Comment: @Algohi There are only 7 days in a week... I'm sure you can type it out faster than hunting for ``DataPaclets`...`` (if it existed). I was just too lazy to type out all the months :) Here, use this: `Thread[{"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wednes", "Thurs", "Fri", "Satur"} ~~ "day"]`

Comment: yes you are right :) :) :). you know, It is some times fun to know how to do things differently even if they are simple and also it is good to know the hidden parts in MMA. :)